# How to avoid inconvenience for users when loading an ad banner?

Tags: android, admob

I don't want to display an ad banner in first time, just load the ad on 3rd, 6th,9th times. How can i do ? 
If i want the ad banner automatically close after 1 minutes, how can i do ? 
And is there any way if the user want to close the ad ?

This is following @Nana Ghartey :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

loadTimedAd();
autoCloseAd() ;
}


int adCounter;    
private void loadTimedAd() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        adCounter = sharedPrefs.getInt("prefAdCounter", 0);
if (adCounter % 2 == 0 && connectedToNet())
adshow();
    //            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

else PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                        .putInt("prefAdCounter", ++adCounter).commit();

    }
private boolean connectedToNet() {
    final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
boolean isAdClosed = false;


protected void adshow() {

    RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.camerar);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     rlParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT,RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT );

    final AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1167514687331347/1312527819");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    mainLayout.addView(adView, rlParams);

    AdRequest adreq = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adreq);
     }

private void autoCloseAd(){
              new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                   if(isAdClosed){
                                       //AdView adView = new AdView(this);
                                       adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                   isAdClosed = true;
                                   }
                               }
                        }, 3000);
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include the code showing us what you have tried so far and what did not work.

Comment: Oh . My code worked:     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build(); adView.loadAd(adRequest);    , but i don't know how to automatically close the ad banner . and i don't want my app show the ad banner in the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Concerning the first issue, You can use a counter to show ads at particular times. For example to load the ads only at the 3rd, 6th, 9th, 12th ...times when connected to the internet:**

```
int adCounter;

private void loadTimedAd() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        adCounter = sharedPrefs.getInt("prefAdCounter", 0);
if (adCounter % 3 == 0 && connectedToNet())
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            else PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit()
                        .putInt("prefAdCounter", ++adCounter).commit();

    }
```

**//method to check if internet is connected**

```
private boolean connectedToNet() {
        final ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

This requires the permission:
   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

**Concerning your second issue, you can use the banner ad's visibility flags to automatically hide the ads after some time. For instance to hide the ad after a minute**

```
boolean isAdClosed = false;

private void autoCloseAd(){
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       if(isAdClosed){
                       adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       isAdClosed = true;
                       }
                   }
            }, 60000);
}
```

Then finally in your onCreate() call the methods

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad);
    loadTimedAd();
    autoCloseAd();
}
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: your idea so great but i got some problem . 1st , i want the counter count the times when user opened app. 2nd, the ad didn't close. Can you help me revise my code ? I will update my question including code .

Comment: yes, i did , but method autocloseAd() not work because an error "adView cannot be resolved" in **adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);**. Can you help me conect the adView to my adView .

Comment: It got an error so i don't got the logcat for you. you can see my code in the question that i've updated. error "adView cannot be resolved" in line **adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);**

Comment: In your onCreate() do you create the adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.ad); like I've done above?